# ¿Cómo obtener el ID del Spinner en vez de su Value and Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, webservice

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación de Android Studio con Web Service, mi problema es que uso un Spinner y necesito capturar el ID de este más no el valor del Spinner.¿Alguna solución?

Utilizo un webService hecho en C#

```
  private class CargarCombo extends AsyncTask<String,String,Boolean> {

        private CatalogoSpinner[] catalogoCatalogoSpinner;

        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {

            boolean resul = true;

            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
            PropertyInfo pro = new PropertyInfo();
            pro.setName("consulta");
            pro.setValue("SELECT DESCRIPCION, ID_PRODUCTO_FINANCIERO AS ID FROM CAT_PRODUCTO_FINANCIERO");
            pro.setType(String.class);
            request.addProperty(pro);

            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet = true;

            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

            HttpTransportSE transporte = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

            try
            {
                transporte.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                // SoapObject resSoap = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
                SoapObject resSoap =(SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
```

Comment: Estas usando Xamarin? te refieres a el id de la vista Spinner? o del elemento cargado.

Comment: utilizo Android Studio y el web service esta hecho en c#